# What does $\langle i \rangle$ mean or imply?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Working on an isomorphism problem involving $\mathbb Z_4$ and $\langle i \rangle$,

What does $\langle i \rangle$ mean or imply?

My understanding is that $\langle i \rangle$ is a finite cycle group of order $4$ under multiplication   such that :

$$\langle i \rangle = \{ i^0, i^1, i^2, i^3, i^4 \} = \{ 1, i, -1, - i \}$$

Is this formulation accurate?

Comment: Yes. You are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,
$\langle i\rangle  = \{i^0, i^1, i^2, \dots\}$ is the cyclic group generated by $i$.

Comment: But, what you show is here is that $<i>$ is infinite, it contradicts (or leave uncertain) my statement that $<i>$ is finite and has an order 4.

Comment: If in your case i is the imaginary unit, then your statement was correct, in that $\langle i \rangle = \{i^0, i^1, i^2 \dots\} = \{1, i , -1, -i \}$ \\ Note that $i^4 =1 = i^0$ so the cyclic subgroup has order 4